# Call classes by body class

Tags: css, class

Is it possible to call more classes inside a body class? I have an example.

I have an body class "class-for-body". With this body class I specify other classes on that page only. What I always do is like this:

```
body.class-for-body .other-class,
body.class-for-body .other-class-new,
body.class-for-body .other-class-more,
body.class-for-body .other-class-left {
    styling shizzle
}
```

But I also have an body with class "class-for-newbody" with the same subclasses:

```
body.class-for-newbody .other-class,
body.class-for-newbody .other-class-new,
body.class-for-newbody .other-class-more,
body.class-for-newbody .other-class-left {
    styling shizzle
}
```

Is there a way to call them together?

Regards,
Robert

Comment: You could use a CSS preprocessor or just combine the two sets of rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use wildcard selectors, for example ...

```
body[class*='class-for-'] {
  /* todo */
}
```